# Rosa Parks is a [symbol?] for the civil rights movement?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What's the term used to describe a figure who comes to represent a movement in the common perception of the population?

I don't mean a *leader* or a *spokesperson*, I'm meaning more that they're a mascot for the movement.

Comment: I suggested an edit to avoid using _mascot_ in reference to Rosa Parks. It seems to me that it could be interpreted negatively. The edit was rejected, but I encourage you to consider editing your post: (http://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/202151)

Comment: I will note that "mascot" tends to be used (in the US) to refer to either an animal or some sort of comic character or clown, an inappropriate way to refer to Ms Parks.  There are certainly several other terms which are more appropriate.

Comment: "Poster child" has been suggested several times, but it carries a sort of "downer" connotation.  So far as I know, the term originates from posters of sad-eyed crippled children during and after the [polio epidemic](http://www.healthline.com/health/worst-disease-outbreaks-history#Polio9) in the US during the middle of the 20th Century.  The purpose was to play on the sympathies of the public.  The children pictured in the posters rarely had a "story" of an note, but their appearance attracted sympathy (and money).

Comment: @HotLicks But that is the entire point of OPs question, that he is looking for a word other than mascot. If he knew a word other than mascot he wouldn't need to ask this question.

Comment: @SGR - The original question used "mascot" as the prototype word.  I was merely explaining why that word is not appropriate, more to readers than to the OP.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to answer, but have you considered "key figure"? Rosa Parks is a key figure in the civil rights movement. The idiom "key figure" means an important person in an event; a person central to an event.

Comment: @HotLicks Huh - I actually tend to think of "poster child" as something more like [this fella](http://www.bsamuseum.org/NationalScoutingMuseum/media/National-Scouting-Museum-Library/Collection%20Items/I-Will-Do-My-Best-1943.jpg?ext=.jpg) - slightly positive connotation, but just generally "the person they'd put on posters as a perfect (or at least photogenic) example of this thing"

Comment: @Amadeus9 - No, [this](http://www.elvisinfonet.com/image-files/marchofdimes_poster_1955.jpg) is a poster child.  And [this](https://envisioningtheamericandream.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/health-march-of-dimes-salk-vaccine-trials.jpg).  And [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/--vMnoTPZQMc/VSqflLr9WiI/AAAAAAAAIYE/24YnSm-3fIQ/s1600/march%2Bof%2Bdimes%2Bposter.jpg).

Comment: @ab2 no the question is protected it requires 10 rep to answer and the 100 from the association bonus doesn't count.

Comment: You have at least 8 good answers to your question.  Is one of them acceptable?  Of course, you are not obliged to accept any answer and the only criterion is what answer best suits you.  Has this just slipped your mind?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

***icon***. from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/icon) (TFD)

> a person or thing regarded as a symbol of a belief, nation, community,
> or cultural movement

The word **icon** originally had a deep religious significance, being (TFD)

> A representation or picture of a sacred or sanctified Christian
> personage, traditionally used and venerated in the Eastern Church.

Rosa Parks has an almost religious significance for the Civil Rights Movement and for many of her admirers.

The words **icon** or **iconic** are used much more broadly, for example a fashion magazine might describe a simple little black dress (wildly overpriced)  *iconic*.  And *Icon* in Computerese means "a pictorial representation of a facility available on a computer system" (TFD), but none of these meanings should detract from the more profound meaning that Rosa Parks exemplifies.

Comment: Icon was the first that occurred to me, or maybe "paragon."

Comment: Somewhat ironically, Rosa Parks became an icon because she was an [iconoclast (person who destroys icons.)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iconoclast)
Rosa Parks was an iconoclast, because she challenged (and literally defied) the widely accepted beliefs of her day, which ultimately led to her becoming an icon herself.

Comment: I know this is now a common use, but I don't like the confusion of the person and the image.  An icon was an image, the person depicted on it was a saint.  In our information-centered culture, we lose the distinction.  I am ok with Pop icon, etc. because those people basically *are* their images.  Parks' participation in her cause was more real.

Comment: @jobermark A good illustration of the way language changes -- often not logically!

Comment: "Rosa Parks, who has resided in the State of Michigan since 1957, has become a living **icon** for freedom in America." [Congressional gold medal award, May 4,1999](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/PLAW-106publ26/html/PLAW-106publ26.htm)

Answer (score 43):

#### Embodiment

> Rosa Parks not only launched this new paradigm but incorporated all
>   those that preceded it: Old Leftism, New Deal liberalism, unionism,
>   NAACP legalism and gradualism. **She was an embodiment of the civil
>   rights movement** to that moment, even if the impression persists that
>   she was a simple old lady with aching feet.

[Rosa Parks: The story behind her sitting down](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/obit/2005/10/rosa_parks.html) - By Diane McWhorter - Slate Magazine, 2005. Emphasis mine.

**Embodiment** means:

> Someone or something that is a perfect representative or example of a
>   quality, idea, etc.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embodiment)

Answer (score 38):

"Pioneer", "hero", "champion", or "role model" perhaps could fit also.

[***pioneer***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pioneer)

> 1. a person who is among those who first enter or settle a region, thus opening it for occupation and development by others.
> 2. one who is first or among the earliest in any field of inquiry, enterprise, or progress.

She was certainly one of the first activists in the Civil Rights Movement.

[***hero***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hero)

> 2. A person noted for feats of courage or nobility of purpose, especially one who has risked or sacrificed his or her life

She demonstrated courage and risked punishment for her civil disobedience.

[***champion***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/champion)

> 3. An ardent defender or supporter of a cause or another person

Her actions were not just for her own self-interests.

[***role model***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/role%20model)

> A person who serves as a model in a particular behavioral or social role for another person to emulate.

And she served as a model for other acts of civil disobedience.

Answer (score 22):

How about ***emblem***, ***symbol***, ***harbinger***, or ***herald***?

From Merriam-Webster:

> [***emblem***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emblem): a person
>   or thing that represents an idea
>
> [***symbol***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/symbol): an
>   action, object, event, etc., that expresses or represents a particular
>   idea or quality

- "Rosa Parks was an ***emblem*** of the civil rights movement."
- "Rosa Parks was a ***symbol*** of the civil rights movement."

These seem rather close to the OP's "mascot".

The following also apply to Rosa Parks, but they might not be as close to the word the OP is seeking:

> [***harbinger***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harbinger):
>   one that pioneers in or initiates a major change; one that presages or foreshadows what is to come
>
> [***herald***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/herald): one that
>   precedes or foreshadows

- "Rosa Parks was a ***harbinger*** of the civil rights movement."
- "Rosa Parks was a ***herald*** of the civil rights movement."

Comment: Yeah, but she is *real* not merely representational or information-bearing

Comment: harbinger usually has a negative connotation to it. I have not yet seen it being used to foretell a positive or happy event.

Comment: The original harbingers were the people who went ahead of troops or a royal procession to make sure that all the VIPs had somewhere to stay that night, food was sorted out etc. From the point of view of people on the route they were therefore the first signs that they were in for a difficult and dangerous time.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid and Paul Johnson Thanks for the comments. I've always considered *harbinger* to be positive, negative, or neutral depending on whether "what is to come" is considered positive, negative, or neutral. One can quickly find dictionary examples of the meaning of *harbinger* I'm invoking. For example: "Frost is a harbinger of winter" and "Witch hazels are harbingers of spring." There is nothing inherently negative about this sense of *harbinger*.

Answer (score 17):

I'd like to suggest **torchbearer** as in the following sentence: In refusing to relinquish her seat, Rosa Parks became a **torchbearer** for the American Civil Rights Movement.

> **torchbearer:** Someone in the forefront of a campaign, crusade, or movement.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/torchbearer)

Answer (score 14):

In the sense that the term suggests no actual power, as the person is only perceived as the leader of a movement, I am thinking of **figurehead**:

> a person who is called the head or chief of something but who has no
>   real power

[source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/figurehead?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld): Merriam-Webster

The figurehead originally was the carved figure on a ship's bow.

Comment: I think this has too much of a negative (or at least passive) connotation.

Comment: A figurehead appears to hold power.  She did not, other than as someone to emulate.

Answer (score 12):

If a single person is synonymous with an idea, they can be described as the *face* of that idea. It suggests that their physical appearance is so well-known that simply observing it evokes thoughts of the idea they represent. Likewise, it suggests that thinking of the idea itself invariably evokes imagery of that person's physical appearance.

I've written this example to demonstrate:

> One picture of Rosa Parks is all it takes to remind us of how far we've come. She's truly the *face* of the American civil rights movement.

Comment: This is the best one yet.  Signifies uniqueness and has no negative connotation.

Comment: +1 I like this, but is the sentence your own or is it a quotation?  If the latter, please provide the source and a link.  If your own,  please credit yourself!

Comment: @ab2 It's my own, but it's packed with cliche, so I'm not exactly proud of it. :)

Answer (score 10):

Folks are factoring the meaning too much.  She is *both* an embodiment and a 'poster-child' so she is an:

> exemplar - a person or thing serving as a typical example or excellent model.

or a

> paragon - a person or thing regarded as a perfect example of a particular quality.

[Oxford Dictionaries, paragon](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paragon)

Answer (score 7):

As a native speaker, "hero" and/or "poster child" sound best to me.

"Hero" doesn't imply uniqueness.  She could be one of many.  There's usually only one "mascot" for a team or cause.

"Poster child" suggests uniqueness, but it also doesn't have the positive connotation of "hero".  Someone can be the "poster child" for something entirely negative.

"Figurehead" is bad because it has negative implications.  It brings to mind a leader who isn't really a leader; someone else is really in charge.

Several of the others ("symbol", "embodiment", "mascot") usually aren't used to refer to specific individuals. "Mascot" in particular, when applied to Parks, sounds vaguely insulting.  As if she were cynically used to promote the cause.  If that's the meaning you're trying to convey then great, but otherwise I'd avoid "mascot".

Comment: "Poster child" is good but it seems a little reductive to use for Rosa Parks...

Comment: Unfortunately, "poster child" carries something of a demeaning connotation.

Comment: As a native native speaker (read: BrE) these are acceptable but sound a bit odd.